# how to get csvkit to convert very wide xlsx files -- weird error messages

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, file-conversion

I've been trying to convert a number of xlsx files which are very wide (over 200 columns) into csv files so I can aggregate them into a single file for analysis. I've been trying to use csvkit, but it just hangs on the files.

The error message when I switch the verbose mode on varies each time I run it here's one:

```
C:\_analysis>in2csv -v 85910332_PE20160101_RECLMEXP.xlsx > test.csv
c:\python35\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\names\named_range.py:121: UserWarning: Discarded range with reserved name
  warnings.warn("Discarded range with reserved name")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\Scripts\in2csv-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('csvkit==0.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'in2csv')()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\csvkit\utilities\in2csv.py", line 82, in launch_new_instance
    utility.main()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\csvkit\utilities\in2csv.py", line 76, in main
    data = convert.convert(self.input_file, filetype, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\csvkit\convert\__init__.py", line 39, in convert
    return xlsx2csv(f, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\csvkit\convert\xlsx.py", line 66, in xlsx2csv
    value = c.value
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\read_only.py", line 107, in value
    if self.data_type == 'b':
KeyboardInterrupt
```

When I ran it again, the error was slightly different:

```
C:\_analysis>in2csv -v 85910332_PE20160101_RECLMEXP.xlsx > test.csv
c:\python35\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\names\named_range.py:121: UserWarning: Discarded range with reserved name
  warnings.warn("Discarded range with reserved name")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\Scripts\in2csv-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('csvkit==0.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'in2csv')()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\csvkit\utilities\in2csv.py", line 82, in launch_new_instance
    utility.main()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\csvkit\utilities\in2csv.py", line 76, in main
    data = convert.convert(self.input_file, filetype, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\csvkit\convert\__init__.py", line 39, in convert
    return xlsx2csv(f, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\csvkit\convert\xlsx.py", line 58, in xlsx2csv
    for i, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows()):
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\iter_worksheet.py", line 103, in get_squared_range
    for _event, element in p:
  File "c:\python35\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1290, in __next__
    for event in self._parser.read_events():
  File "c:\python35\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1257, in read_events
    index = self._index
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any ideas?

I'm running Windows 10, the source files are in Excel 2013, and Python 3.5.1 and the following library versions
csvkit==0.9.1
jdcal==1.2
numpy==1.10.2
openpyxl==2.2.0b1
python-dateutil==2.2
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.13
xlrd==1.0.0